# Scroll in Android Native app using robot framework

Tags: android, python, appium, robotframework

How to scroll to the bottom of the page in android native app using appium/python/robot-framework ? I have tried the following ways but doesn't work
**driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(144, 1532)")**
AND
**driver.execute_script('mobile: scroll', {'duration': 1, 'startX': 48, 'startY': 892, 'endX': 144, 'endY': 1532})**

Answer (score 0):

the appium library should have a _touch.py file controlling scrolls or "swipes"

**_touch.py**

```
def swipe(self, start_x, start_y, end_x, end_y, duration=1000):
    """
    Swipe from one point to another point, for an optional duration.
    """
    driver = self._current_application()
    driver.swipe(start_x, start_y, end_x, end_y, duration)
```

or

```
def scroll(self, start_locator, end_locator):
    """
    Scrolls from one element to another
    Key attributes for arbitrary elements are `id` and `name`. See
    `introduction` for details about locating elements.
    """
    el1 = self._element_find(start_locator, True, True)
    el2 = self._element_find(end_locator, True, True)
    driver = self._current_application()
    driver.scroll(el1, el2)
```